# SignalR connection issue with a server

Tags: c#, signalr

So I recently bought a vps to try SignalR in my project, I used this example : [Simple SignalR Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5162436/Simple-SignalR-Server-and-Client-Applications-Demo)

Unfortunately though I do not have any experience with such things, I uploaded the ServerSide program on my vps and tried to connect with it, but I get the following error : `An error occurred while sending the request.` 
More Detailed :

```
   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.dll
   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ip:9080
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) / System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ip:9080
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

So I was wondering if I'm doing anything wrong here, or need to do any specific settings/setups on my server

by the way my goal is to have a connection with a server and get real-time data for my project, so if there's any better alternatives, would appreciate suggestions

Answer (score 0):

well, found the solution, my firewall was preventing the connection